# Which format is preferable for tflite model NCHW or NHWC?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensorflow-lite

For gpus nchw mode is preferrable due to speed benefits, but what is the preferable mode in terms of mobile perfomance for tflite model?
Now converting from pytorch to tflite yields a working nchw model but is this mode optimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TensorFlow Lite's matrix multiplication library, for convolution 2d and so on, prefers NHWC inputs .

The TFLite converter tries to automatically transform the given NCHW weights to the corresponding NHWC weights if the given weights are constant to perform well on mobile. If the given weights are not constants, the converter will add a transpose operator after the NCHW weights to choose the NHWC's based convolution 2d algorithm for mobile.

Comment: I'm converting from pytorch to tflite(through onnx and tensorflow) and it introduces transpose operators before and after each conv. Is there a way to convert onnx(channels first) to tensorflow(channels last) to fully integrate channels last flow and avoid all unnecessary transpose ops?

Comment: If you can keep weights as constant values in your model, constant folding can be applied to NCHW formatted constant weights and the transposed weight will be recorded and the transpose operators can be gone.

Comment: The conv weights are constant and aren't getting transposed
But the model input is obviously not constant and it is getting transposed 
To clarify here it how it looks on netron https://i.imgur.com/ud1xPGa.png
Is there a way to avoid the transposes of the data itself? Conv weights are converted fine

Comment: I think it would be better to request a feature at the library that is responsible for converting from onnx to tensorflow. If the TF model itself is designed in that way, the TFLite converter does not have much choices for this case since it certainly needs to respect the user inputs as well.